# How to make a WebView?

Tags: android

I have no idea on how.

Let me post my code. The code here is the basic Hello, World! Activity.

```
 package com.apw.games.rpg.medieval;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;

public class Site extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.site);
          }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);     
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Then, in your `site.xml`, place a `WebView` element with ID `@+id/webview`.

Comment: Wil this load it in y app or through the browser?

Comment: Why not just try it? It opens in the app.

Comment: Also, don't forget to declare the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest.

Comment: Yah just realized that when it wouldn't load sating webpage isn't available

Comment: Now,, How do I show a loading bar at the top of page?